# How can I migrate my MongoDB to RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

How can I migrate my MongoDB collections to RethinkDB tables?

I'm not concerned about changing my old Mongo `_id`'s to Rethink `id`'s because they will be ignored in my implementation, and I'm not concerned about them cluttering my data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wrote a quick BASH script to solve this.  Because I only had the JavaScript RethinkDB driver, I had to **[install the python driver](http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/python/) first** so I could use `rethinkdb import`.

For this example, I am migrating the mongo collections: `users`, `pinboards`, and `analytics`; add your collections as needed to the following BASH command:

```
for collection in users pinboards analytics; \
do \
  mongoexport \
    --host my.mongo.server \
    --db my_mongo_database \
    --collection $collection \
  > $collection.json; \
  rethinkdb import \
    --file $collection.json \
    --table my_rethink_database.$collection; \
  rm $collection.json; \
done
```

Don't forget to **change the names of your collections, host, and database**.  Also, adjust arguments to [`mongoexport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) and [`rethinkdb import`](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/importing/) as needed.

This is quick and dirty, but I hope it gets someone started in the right direction!

Comment: Quick follow up: You can remove lingering `_id`'s (and `__v`'s if you used Mongoose) with [this recipe](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/cookbook/javascript/#removing-a-field-from-a-document). If I'm not mistaken, you can do this to an entire table by simply excluding the `.get("1")` method from the chain.