# Move binary data from mongoDB to rethinkDB

Tags: mongodb, rethinkdb

I am trying to move data from mongo to rethinkand. Nothing works so far.
The first thing I tried was this:

`mongoexport -h 127.0.0.1 -d basal -c tickets -o tickets.json`

Export it as json and then ...

`rethinkdb import -f tickets.json --table basal.tickets --format json`

Import it as json. Seems easy. Does not work though...

I get this error:

```
0 rows imported in 1 table
ReQL error during 'import': String `ÿØÿá` (truncated) contains NULL byte at offset 8.
ReQL error during 'import': String `PNG

` (truncated) contains NULL byte at offset 9.
ReQL error during 'import': String `ÿØÿá` (truncated) contains NULL byte at offset 8.
ReQL error during 'import': String `PNG

` (truncated) contains NULL byte at offset 9.
Errors occurred during import
```

The problematic data in question is a field with a binary image attachment.

The attachment field looks like this (truncated):

```
{"attach":[{"name":"image001.png","size":20745,"disp":"in
line","cid":"image001.png@01D0411E.BD3054F0","type":"image/png","body":"<U+0089>PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0001>\u0000\u
0000\u0001\u0000\b\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000¥*<U+008D>º\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001sRGB ......"} ...]}
```

Any ideas on how I could import fields with binary values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I migrate my MongoDB to RethinkDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240655/how-can-i-migrate-my-mongodb-to-rethinkdb)

Comment: I have seen the earlier question. It does not help me to resolve the problem and errors.

Comment: How do the documents which fail import look in MongoDB and how would you want them to look after being imported into RethinkDB?

Comment: By the way: `ÿØÿá` looks like a problem with different character encodings being used. Seems like MongoDB exports in a different encoding than RethinkDB uses during import. I am not sure which encoding which database uses, but when you find out it should be easy to fix with any better text editor.

Comment: @Philipp Do you want me to provide the schema? I want them to look exactly the same minus mongo's "_id". Otherwise no field change or json structure

Comment: @r.sendecky I would like you to post an example of a document which fails importing.

Comment: @Philipp I am working on it now, I think it is to do with some binary fields ... In some documents, I have binary values. This is most likely the problem...

Comment: @Philipp I added the part that causes the problem. It is not the whole document but a single field with an image attachment. Thank you for any help or idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RethinkDB doesn't currently support NULL bytes in strings.  We offer an `r.binary` pseudotype to get around that.  What I would do is write a script that reads your input data row by row, parses it, replaces `'body: '...\u0000...'` with `'body: r.binary('...\u0000...')` in that row, and then inserts that row.

Comment: Thank you. Does not help much but at least makes things clear.

Comment: It seems to happen with mongo ObjectIDs too.